# Ksh: Best way to append one file to another inside of a pipe

Tags: shell, pipe, ksh

I have an excel-like DAT file with multiple columns, and I plan to project 3 columns from it using `cut`, then so all sorts of other manipulations (sorting rows, filtering rows, etc.).  The script looks something like this:

```
cut -f1,2,3 -d"|" file1.DAT | 
    sort -r |
        sort -u -k1,1 | 
            sed "s/ //g" | ... > res
```

I have a second DAT file with more content; this file already has the 3 columns I need.
The question is, how can I append (or prepend) this file with the first one in the pipeline so that I can continue sorting the combined files? (preferably without creating temp files)

Is something of this form possible?

```
cut -f1,2,3 -d"|" file1.DAT |
    DO SOMETING HERE | 
        sort -r | 
            sort -u -k1,1 | ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, `DO SOMETHING HERE` should be

```
cat - file2.DAT
```

That will con`cat`enate stdin (received from the pipe, the output of `cut`) and the other file. To do it the other way around,

```
cat file2.DAT -
```

The `-` by itself represents stdin or stdout in several tools (`cat`, `diff`, and `tar` for example). Since `cat` copies files to stdout in the order you name them, you can copy stdin in any place you want in the sequence.